# How to visualize ordered sequences in a bar plot

Tags: pgfplots

I want to visualize sequences of actions. My first idea was to use stacked bar plots from pgfplot for this purpose, however, all examples I can find visualize data where each item is given as pair of a coordinate and a length. I would like to use triplets consisting of a coordinate, a length and a category as well.

Given the example below, I want to have a arbitrary order of the 'actions' and also have the same action occur multiple times. I could achieve this manually, however, for larger plots (which I will have) this would be infeasible. Any suggestions are most welcome.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xbar stacked, bar width=15pt, 
  enlargelimits=0.15, legend style={at={(0.5,-0.30)},
  anchor=north,legend columns=-1}, xlabel={time [s]}, 
  symbolic y coords={P1, P2}, ytick=data,
  y tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
]
\addplot+[xbar] plot coordinates {(1,P1) (2,P2)};
\addplot+[xbar] plot coordinates {(1,P1) (1,P2)};
\addplot+[xbar] plot coordinates {(6,P1) (5,P2)};
\addplot+[xbar] plot coordinates {(4,P1) (2,P2)};
\legend{\strut Action1, \strut Action2, \strut Action3, \strut Action4}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example of a bar plot to be changed]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Most probably PGFPlots will be the wrong tool to do this. But let's wait a few days. Maybe someone has a genius idea.

Answer (score 1):

I found one potential solution - not using pgfplot - this is not exactly what I had in mind, but it can easily be tweaked to do the job

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\def\theyearwidth{1.5pt}
\def\mystrut{\rule{0ex}{1ex}}
\def\myyrstrut{\rule[-1ex]{0ex}{2ex}}
\newlength\yrsfboxrule
\yrsfboxrule .4\fboxrule
\newcommand\yearwidth[1]{\def\theyearwidth{#1}\ignorespaces}

\newcommand\skipyears[2][black]{%
\fboxrule\yrsfboxrule%
\fboxsep=-\yrsfboxrule%
\fcolorbox{#1}{#1}{\mystrut\hspace{#2}}%
\ignorespaces%
}
\newcommand\showyear[2][black]{%
\fboxsep=0pt%
\stackon{%
\colorbox{#1}{\strut\hspace{\theyearwidth}}%
}{\sffamily\tiny#2}%
\ignorespaces%
}
\begin{document}  
\yearwidth{0.8pt}
\showyear{0}
\skipyears[gray]{0.8118cm}
\showyear{49}
\skipyears[blue]{1.8808cm}
\showyear{162}
\skipyears[gray]{0.382cm}
\showyear{}
\end{document}
```

[image]